# Data feed to javascript via Rshiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to send the filtered_data.csv produced as output to javascript so that the data can be used for cool visualisation supported by javascript , I am aware its possible to use htmlwidgets in shiny and various d3 supported libraries , however not my requirement in this case. Any pointers on how can i achieve a connection between Rshiny/R and Javascript to push the data would be helpful

```
shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        title = 'ApplicationA',
        DT::dataTableOutput("dt"),
        theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
        p("Notice that the 'rows_all' attribute grabs the row indices of the data."),
        verbatimTextOutput("filtered_row"),


        downloadButton(outputId = "download_filtered",
                       label = "Download Filtered Data")
      )
    ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
      output$dt <- 
        DT::renderDataTable(
          datatable(cleandata,
                    filter = "top")
        )

      output$filtered_row <- 
        renderPrint({
          input[["dt_rows_all"]]
        })


      output$download_filtered <- 
        downloadHandler(
          filename = "Filtered Data.csv",
          content = function(file){
            write.csv(cleandata[input[["dt_rows_all"]], ],
                      file)
          }
        )
    })
)
```

Comment: Hi Neha, Where would you write your js code? I mean is it part of Shiny or a different app?

Comment: @amrrs its a different application written by someone else

Comment: see http://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/

Comment: I think thats the shiny-tip, youre looking for https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/message-r-to-javascript